# how to identify a mounted external volume?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I have the following to identify if a volume is mounted:

```
on volumeMounted:aNotification
        set volumeName to (NSWorkspaceVolumeLocalizedNameKey of aNotification's userInfo) as text
        if volumeName is "myVolume" then
           --do something 
        end if
    end volumeMounted:
    
    on volumeUnmounted:aNotification
        set volumeName to (NSWorkspaceVolumeLocalizedNameKey of aNotification's userInfo) as text
        if volumeName is "myVolume" then
            --do something
        end if
    end volumeUnmounted:
```

I wanted a way to identify if an external volume is mounted even though it has the same name.

For example:
my internal volume is named "Macintosh HD" and I connect an external volume with the same name
it is only recognizing 1 volume, so I can't unmount both volumes with a Button created in the Interface.

Note: I know I could just right click and ask to eject but I wanted to do that in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

There is another key `NSWorkspaceVolumeURLKey` in the `userInfo` dictionary of the `volumeMounted` notification .

The associated value is the URL of the mount point. You can cast the URL to `alias`. The default folder for mounted volumes is `/Volumes`, the path of the startup volume is always `/`.

Comment: Hi @vadian, could you edit your answer giving an example using the code I posted?